# use the info in a html form through cygwin

Tags: html, cygwin, wget

I'm downloading a web page with wget.

The web page is the screencapture below

[image]

Aim : Get the info "**last update of data : 26.06.2014**" either inside of a variable or inside of a text file.

I know how to retrieve the info with a combination of awk , sed and wget. However, I was wondering if there was an HTML tool or any kind of tool in Unix or Cygwin that can do the retrieval quicker.

Many thanks for reading my question.

PS : I checked on the internet but I found nothing.

Comment: `I know how to retrieve the info with a combination of awk , sed and wget`, then why you added `awk`, `sed` tags?

Comment: Hi Avinash, true. Bigger audience I guess. I will remove the tag.

Comment: Does the header of your web page include the required date? E.g. curl --silent --head http://en.wikipedia.org | grep Last-Modified

Comment: Hi Kokkie, it is an idea but I don't have such a header in my webpage.

Comment: It seems that `sed`and `awk` are the best options so far. Sad.